# Can only access the first element of an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have code that takes 2 files and puts the content into an array:

```
$scope.array = [];
$scope.upload = function(event){
var files = event.target.files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = $scope.loaded; 
            reader.readAsText(file);
    };
};
$scope.loaded = function(e){
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.array.push(e.target.result);
});
```

If the array contains: ["1 2 3","4 5 6"]

and I type:

```
$scope.arrayOne=$scope.array[0].split(' ')
```

The output is: ["1","2","3"]

But if I type:

```
$scope.arrayTwo=$scope.array[1].split(' ')
```

I get an error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

However, I can split the second element through HTML:

```
{{array[1].split(' ')}}
```

This outputs: ["4","5","6"]

EDIT: Managed to fix it by adding

```
$scope.$watch('array', function(){
```

In front of

```
$scope.arrayOne = $scope.array[1].split(' ');
```

Thanks for the help in the comments.

Comment: When do you call `$scope.arrayOne=$scope.array[1].split(' ')`?

Comment: I call it after $scope.loaded = function(e){

Comment: I think your problem is that you are calling this function before the array is defined or whatever is being put into the array is undefined. Try putting a check in to only run the code when it is not undefined

Comment: I'm still getting used to JS/Angular so I'm not to sure how to do that, i tried this :  $scope.arrayTwo = function(){
   if (typeof array !== 'undefined' && array.length > 0) {
    var text = $scope.array[0].split(' ');
    return text;
   };
  }; 

But it still came up with the same error.

Comment: @Alte wrap your load function into $.watch. It will ensure the source will be called if will be loaded and ready.

Comment: I added this:  $scope.$watch('array', function(){
  $scope.loaded = function(e){

But i still got the same error.